# how to add messagebundlefile for language . properties in java

Tags: java

i likely to convert the English words into  hindi ...
by the use of...

**java.util.Locale;**

**java.util.ResourceBundle;**

or keyword file(where all word are asigned)in textfile

like this

loginform.userid=प्रयोक्ता आईडी

loginform.password=पासवर्ड

loginform.submit=प्रस्तुत करना

loginform.reset=रीसेट करें

and use it as a messagebundle en_hi.properties......

how do i use or convert the text file into .properties??

and use in my program....

Comment: You don't need to convert anything.  Just save the file with .properties extension.

Comment: basically i need to know that how to convert text file into filename.properties for java  Intellij program....

Comment: it convert the text file into unicode like in text file{         loginform.userid=प्रयोक्ता आईडी

loginform.password=पासवर्ड

loginform.submit=प्रस्तुत करना

loginform.reset=रीसेट करें        }and then in . properties file loginform.userid=\u092a\u094d\u0930\u092f\u094b\u0915\u094d\u0924\u093e \u0906\u0908\u0921\u0940
loginform.password=\u092a\u093e\u0938\u0935\u0930\u094d\u0921
loginform.submit=\u092a\u094d\u0930\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0941\u0924 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u093e
loginform.reset=\u0930\u0940\u0938\u0947\u091f \u0915\u0930\u0947\u0902

Comment: It runs native2ascii utility if the property file is not stored in UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 1):

Save this file as `messagebundle_hi.properties`

```
 ResourceBundle labels =
     ResourceBundle.getBundle("messagebundle",new Locale("hi", "IN"));
```

You can find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)